# Vectorized spatial distance between values in multidimensional arrays

Tags: scipy, scipy-spatial

Given an `(2,2,3,3,3)` array of 3D-cartesian coordinates along the last dimension, what is the syntax for computing the Euclidean between pairwise values in XA and XB using `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist` to yield an output array with shape `(2, 3, 3)`?

```
XA = np.random.normal(size=(2,2,3,3,3))
XB = np.random.normal(size=(2,2,3,3,3))
dist = cdist(XA[:, 0, ...], XB[:, 1, ...], 'seuclidean')
```

Returns `ValueError: XA must be a 2-dimensional array`. As such, alternative to loops what is the pythonic syntax for computing `cdist(XA[:, 0], XB[:, 1])`?

Comment: If the coordinates are in the last axis, how you get an output shape of (2,3,3) out?

Comment: @DSM I am not sure if that is where my own misunderstanding is, but both `XA[:, 0]` and `XB[:, 1]` have shapes `(2,3,3,3)` and given the distance computation along the last axis I expect the resulting array shape `(2,3,3)`.

Comment: Ah, I think I see my confusion -- I think cdist may compute more distances than you care about.  It'll compute all the cross distances, so basically num_XA_points * num_XB_points.  But you only want the num_XA = num_XB pairwise distances, right?

Comment: Oh damn! Yes, I only want num_XA = num_XB pairwise distances. So I probably need to be using `pdist` here, yes?

Comment: I don't think so; that returns all the _internal_ cross distances in what it gets.  I'm actually not sure of the right way to do what you want, but at least now I know what it is. :-)

Comment: Can you provide a (simplified?) input/output example?

Comment: There are `2*2*3*3 = 36` points in `XA` (and same in `XB`), so, if I understand correctly, you should have 36 distances too... why the output dim equal to `(2, 3, 3)`?

Comment: @xdze2: the OP selects the 0th member of axis=1 for the left-hand-side and the 1st member of axis=1 for the right-hand side, so the second 2 in your multiplication isn't there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this doing the job? if only pairwise distances are needed, and the coordinates are on the last dimension:

```
import numpy as np

XA = np.random.normal(size=(2,2,3,3,3))
XB = np.random.normal(size=(2,2,3,3,3))

distances = np.sqrt(np.sum((XA - XB)**2, axis=-1))
```

but here `distances.shape` is `(2, 2, 3, 3)`...

Comment: Yes, that works. I was totally sidetracked by `np.cdist` and `np.pdist`. Just needed basic operation modules. I was also given an equivalent solution by a colleague... `np.linalg.norm(XA - XB, axis=-1)`